# Creating a PDF in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf, swift2

I want to be able to be able to create a PDF of my view controller. Essentially, I need a screenshot of the view controller to be exported as a PDF. Apple don't seem to have any documentation on this (for OS X development) in Swift, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Just in case anyone was wondering.. The solution to this problem is as follows (apologies for not posting sooner - I assumed as this was a 'duplicate' question then the answer would lie elsewhere..

```
//  Define the bounds of the view
    let rect: NSRect = self.view.bounds

//  Create a PDF version and save it to the desktop
    self.view.dataWithPDFInsideRect(rect).writeToFile("/Users/Jay/Desktop/test.pdf", atomically: false)

//  Automatically open this newly generated file
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile("/Users/Jay/Desktop/test.pdf")
```

Comment: You need to investigate a little bit more.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile() is a method, part of the CoreText lib.

Comment: @darkndream Question is for OS X, not iOS.

Comment: You are right Eric, i didn't read the OS X part the first time.
So UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile() won't work since it is not on OS X..

And UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile() is not part of Coretext, i'm sorry, it is part of UIKIT lib

Comment: In case anyone was interested, I managed to work it out. Simply create an NSRect using the bounds of the view controller, and then use the dataWithPDFInsideRect function and write to a file.

Comment: @Jay could you answer your question below and add the code you used so I and future visitors can be helped later? That's what Stack Overflow's for.

Comment: @owlswipe I've added the answer above. Apologies for not posting sooner

Comment: @Jay Thank you very much! I don't think the others are really duplicates (or, at least, they don't have good answers).